# Ordering Textbox Lines Ascending to Descending

Tags: vb.net

I want order descending as ascending my Textbox.Lines.

Textbox1.Lines

```
13
71
68
101
54
```

> Output: Expecting

```
101
71
68
54
13
```

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
  Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Lines
        Dim value As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
        For Each line As String In lines
            value.Add(Convert.ToInt32(line))
        Next
        value.Sort()
        TextBox2.Text = value.ToString
```

Linq:

```
Dim lines() As String = Textbox1.Lines
Dim value = lines.Select(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x)).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x)
Textbox2.Text = value.tostring
```

So what i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*value.ToString* will just output the type of the object because an array of integers doesn't know how to print its single  elements. 
You should join together the elements and print the resulting string

```
Textbox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, value)
```